# Zoom with drill-down capability

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement drill-down capability in zoom function, i.e., I want that my initial plot shows, for example, 50 points, and when the user makes zoom the number of points increases to 500.

My attempt consists in redraw inside the zoom function all the points and remove part of them when the zoom scale is under a threshold. As you can see in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ywswguof/), the implementation reproduces the drill-down capability.

However, I suspect that there is a more efficient way to implement the drill-down. Therefore, the question is if I'm in the correct way or there is a standard (more efficient and elegant) way for doing this effect.

My example code:

```
var width = 300,
    height = 300;

var randomX = d3.random.normal(width / 2, 40),
    randomY = d3.random.normal(height / 2, 40);

var data = d3.range(500).map(function() {
  return [randomX(), randomY()];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var zoomBehav = d3.behavior.zoom();

svg.attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .call(zoomBehav
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoom));

// Initial plot
d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
    .data(data, function(d,i) {return i;})
  .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return d[1]; })
    .style("fill", "red");

d3.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function(d, i) {
          if (zoomBehav.scale() < 2) { return i > 50; }
      })
      .remove();


function zoom(){
  var selection = d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data, function(d,i) { return i; });

    selection
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d3.event.translate[0] + d3.event.scale * d[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d3.event.translate[1] + d3.event.scale * d[1]; });

    selection.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d3.event.translate[0] + d3.event.scale * d[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d3.event.translate[1] + d3.event.scale * d[1]; })
        .style("fill", "red");

    d3.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function(d, i) {
          if (zoomBehav.scale() < 2) { return i > 50; }
      })
      .remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in dealing with semantic zoom of elements on an XY canvas, then you'll want to look into d3.geom.quadtree:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom

You can pass your points to a quadtree and they'll be spatially nested. Then, you can tie the nesting level to the zoom level and have automatic grid clustering. It's rather more involved than would fit into this answer, since you have to come up with mechanisms for representing the clustered points, and you'll also need to get into recursive functions to deal with the hierarchical level of points.

Here's an example using quadtrees for semantic zoom and clustering for mapping:

http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/066e20c1ce5008f884eb

Comment: It's not the ideal answer, but it is a good point to start searching more information... thanks!